# How to read data from the serial port in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a script in QT for reading the format packages (AA), (BB), etc from serial port. I open the serial port, but when I go to check inside the QByteArray values, comes back that I could not read any value.

This is my code

```
...
QSerialPort *serialPort = new QSerialPort();
serialPort->setPortName("ttyUSB0");
serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600, QSerialPort::AllDirections);
serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

if (serialPort->isOpen()) {
    qDebug() << "Serial port is open...";
    QByteArray datas = serialPort->readAll();
    if (datas.size() == 0) {
        qDebug() << "Arrived data: 0";
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < datas.size(); i++){
            if (datas.at(i)) {
                qDebug() << datas[i];
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    qDebug() << "OPEN ERROR: " << serialPort->errorString();
}

serialPort->close();
qDebug() << "...serial port is closed!";

return 0;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called `readAll()` immediately after `open()`.  It probably took the computer a few nanoseconds to get from one to the other.

At 9600 baud, each byte of data takes slightly more than one millisecond to transfer.  It would be absolutely impossible for any data to have arrived in that short an interval, so that's why you got no data.

Serial ports don't begin buffering incoming data until you open them (how could they, what baud rate and other settings would be used for receiving and buffering when no program has the port open?)

Use either a blocking read function of some sort (such as `readLine()`) or an event loop that reacts to data when it arrives.

Comment: [`readLine()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readLine) does not block. You have to either use [`waitForReadyRead()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForReadyRead)(not recommended to block the GUI thread), or to start reading when the [`readyRead()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal is emitted.

Comment: In fact, as I entered waitForReadyRead () I can already read something.
Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @Mike: If `readLine()` doesn't block, then the documentation is in desperate need of a rewrite.  Thanks for reinforcing my decision to never ever use Qt.

Comment: however for my case I do not need readLine() because returns the number of bytes read, and I want that returns the packets in the format above. That comes back to me from reading are strange symbols, the problem is the QByteArray?