# Unable to read byte array using QSerialport readAll() method

Tags: c++, qt

I am sending Response to a serial com port, send data is working fine, but for the data sent, there is a response in byte array format. I need 7 byte of data but getting only the 1st byte.

QSerialPort * serial = new QSerialPort();

```
serial->setPortName(serialPortInfo.portName());

if(serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){

    if(!serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600))
             ....
             ....
           serial->write(QByteArray::fromHex(command.toLocal8Bit()));
           //the serial must remain opened

           if(serial->waitForReadyRead(5000)){
               //Data was returned


               QByteArray datas = serial->readAll();

  \
                   if (datas.size() == 0) {
                       qDebug() << "Arrived data: 0";
                   } else {
                       for (int i = 0; i < datas.size(); i++){
                           if (datas.at(i)) {
                               qDebug() << datas[i];
                           }
                       }
                   }

           }else{
               //No data
               qDebug()<<"Time out";
           }

           //I have finish all operation
           serial->close();
       }else{
           qDebug()<<"Serial not opened. Error: "<<serial->errorString();
       }
```

Expected : XYZABC
Actual : X

Comment: In docklight, port is sending right result, so we can't say that there is device fault!!

Comment: Try replacing `if(serial->waitForReadyRead(5000))` with `while(serial->waitForReadyRead(5000))` so it will continue trying to receive data.

Comment: There's no guarantee that all data written will be read with a single call to `readAll()`.  You need to accumulate the data read until you have sufficient to be processed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data from the serial port in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678253/how-to-read-data-from-the-serial-port-in-qt)